# Hair particle color in particle edit mode

Tags: particles, color, hair, particle-edit-mode

[image]

I know that in particle edit mode the hair marks appear black.

But my particles appear light blue. It makes my eyes tired and I don't know exactly where I've chosen.

It looks simple, but I am unable to solve it due to lack of information.

Is there anything in the settings I need to touch?

Answer (score 0):

The selected theme defines the colors. You can change them in the *Preferences*.

Select *Edit > Preferences...* from the main menu.

In the popup dialog, select *Themes*, then expand the *3D Viewport* section.

- here you will find the *Vertex Selected* color which is the color for selected hair particles. It's orange in Blender's dark default theme.
- the *Wire* color defines the color for unselected hair particles. It's black in the dark default theme.

Comment: Thank you. I think I need to look around the basics a bit more.